# Use of CC0 images in an Android app

Tags: copyright, software, creative-commons, public-domain

I'm making an app, and it need some images that the users can use to personalize their phone.

I'm planning to use unsplash.com as images source. The licence says that they are CC0: https://unsplash.com/license

Will I be allowed to use this images (through the API) in my app without risking to get my developer account banned from Google?

This are the Google Play Store ToS: https://play.google.com/about/play-terms.html

Comment: Why the downvote? Isn't this the right place to ask?

Comment: I didn't vote on your question, but I question whether it is on-topic.  It sounds like you essentially want *someone else* to read a license and a ToS and give you a legal opinion of whether the former is allowed under the latter.  The only people who can legally do that are *lawyers*.  And the only entity that can answer your explicit question would be Google.

Comment: Sorry, I was wondering if Google have the right to bypass the CC0 licence of the images, since the app is distributing they through its platform (the Play Store). I don't know anything about law, so I thought to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a license to "copy, modify, distribute and use the photos for free, including commercial purposes," so your account should not get blocked for copyright infringement of those images.

You should consider re-hosting (or at least on-device locally caching) images that will be requested frequently, instead of hotlinking to the original, so that Unsplash isn't having to pay all those bandwidth costs.

It's your responsibility to make sure the rest of the app is still in compliance with the rest of the rules.